# w-screen and h-screen of tailwind are breaking the responsiveness

Tags: css, flexbox, next.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to make a 404 page with Nextjs and typescript. Here are the screenshots:
[image: Screenshot of overflowing]
[image: Screenshot of overflowing 2]

### As you see, I have the scrollbar on both the right and bottom sides and they are breaking the responsiveness.

#### I gave the background color to make this noticeable.

Here's my code...

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import React from "react";

interface Props {}

const ErrorPage: React.FC<Props> = ({}) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <>
      <div className="bg-gray-900 h-screen w-screen flex justify-center items-center absolute z-0">
        <svg
          className="p-6 lg:p-48 fill-current text-gray-300"
          viewBox="0 0 445 202"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          fill="none"
          stroke="currentColor"
          // viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        >
          <path
            d="M137.587 154.953h-22.102V197h-37.6v-42.047H.53v-33.557L72.36 2.803h43.125V124.9h22.102v30.053zM77.886 124.9V40.537L28.966 124.9h48.92zm116.707-23.718c0 22.46 1.842 39.643 5.525 51.547 3.684 11.905 11.23 17.857 22.64 17.857 11.411 0 18.89-5.952 22.44-17.857 3.548-11.904 5.323-29.086 5.323-51.547 0-23.54-1.775-40.97-5.324-52.29s-11.028-16.98-22.438-16.98c-11.41 0-18.957 5.66-22.64 16.98-3.684 11.32-5.526 28.75-5.526 52.29zM222.759.242c24.887 0 42.339 8.76 52.356 26.28 10.018 17.52 15.027 42.406 15.027 74.66s-5.01 57.095-15.027 74.525c-10.017 17.43-27.47 26.145-52.356 26.145-24.887 0-42.339-8.715-52.357-26.145-10.017-17.43-15.026-42.271-15.026-74.525 0-32.254 5.009-57.14 15.026-74.66C180.42 9.001 197.872.241 222.76.241zm221.824 154.711h-22.102V197h-37.6v-42.047h-77.355v-33.557l71.83-118.593h43.125V124.9h22.102v30.053zM384.882 124.9V40.537l-48.92 84.363h48.92z"
            fillRule="nonzero"
          />
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div className="h-screen w-screen flex justify-center items-center relative z-10">
        <div className="p-6 text-center">
          <h2 className="uppercase text-xl lg:text-5xl font-black">
            We are sorry, Page not found!
          </h2>
          <p className="mt-3 uppercase text-sm lg:text-base font-semibold text-gray-900">
            The page you are looking for might have been removed had its name
            changed or is temporarily unavailable.
          </p>
          <div className="text-center">
            <Link href="/">
              <a
                className="mt-6 m-auto bg-primary text-white py-4 px-6 w-1/3 block rounded-full tracking-wide
                font-semibold font-display focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline hover:bg-primaryAccent
                shadow-lg transition-css"
              >
                Back To Homepage
              </a>
            </Link>

            <button
              onClick={() => router.back()}
              className="mt-6 m-auto bg-primary text-white py-4 px-6 w-1/4 block rounded-full tracking-wide
                  font-semibold font-display focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline hover:bg-primaryAccent
                  shadow-lg transition-css"
            >
              Go Back
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default ErrorPage;
```

Is this happening because of h-screen and w-screen or is something wrong with flex? But if I don't use them, I don't make it to work as I am expecting which is placing one div above the other (absolute). I am probably looking at this code for too long and I am lost in space.
So, what am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: Are you still interested in fixing this?

Answer (score 2):

### "width: 100vw" is breaking the page layout. There's a horizontal scrollbar appearing on the page.

That's because the w-screen property means "width: 100vw" (the element with such a property is supposed to consume the whole available device screen space horizontally).

As you have a vertical scrollbar on the page body () (as the body is probably bigger in height than the screen height (= 100vh)), you'll always have less gorizontal space than 100vw, as the horizontal space is also consumed by the vertical scrollbar.

It's not a TailwindCSS-related issue, but rather a CSS-related bug.

The vertical scrollbar's width is usually ~12 px, but it differs between OS'es and screen sizes.

What I think would be better is if CSS would count the available screen width for the 100vw property considering the scrollbar width, like 100vw = real screen width - (**vertical** scrollbar's **width**, *if one is present*).

---

### "(height: 100vh // max-height: 100vh)" is breaking the page layout. There's a vertical scrollbar appearing

That's because the w-screen property means "width: 100vw" (the element with such a property is supposed to consume the whole available device screen space horizontally).

As you have a vertical scrollbar on the page body () (as the body is probably bigger in width than the screen width (= 100vw)), you'll always have less vertical space than 100vh, as the vertical space is also consumed by the horizontal scrollbar.

The horizontal scrollbar's width is usually ~12 px, but it differs between OS'es and screen sizes.

For this case CSS could count the property for the 100vh value like 100vh = real screen height - (**horizontal** scrollbar's **height**, *if one is present*).

What can be done now:

You better use width: 100% and height: 100% properties instead of width: 100vw and height: 100vh

It's always risky to use the vh and vw values. Why would you need that? Semantically, the child should always be smaller than the parent.

This is the same ugly workaround as hiding the problems with overflowing with "overflow-x: hidden".

So your code should look like:

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import React from "react";

interface Props {}

const ErrorPage: React.FC<Props> = ({}) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <>
      <div className="bg-gray-900 h-full w-full flex justify-center items-center absolute z-0">
        <svg
          className="p-6 lg:p-48 fill-current text-gray-300"
          viewBox="0 0 445 202"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          fill="none"
          stroke="currentColor"
          // viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        >
          <path
            d="M137.587 154.953h-22.102V197h-37.6v-42.047H.53v-33.557L72.36 2.803h43.125V124.9h22.102v30.053zM77.886 124.9V40.537L28.966 124.9h48.92zm116.707-23.718c0 22.46 1.842 39.643 5.525 51.547 3.684 11.905 11.23 17.857 22.64 17.857 11.411 0 18.89-5.952 22.44-17.857 3.548-11.904 5.323-29.086 5.323-51.547 0-23.54-1.775-40.97-5.324-52.29s-11.028-16.98-22.438-16.98c-11.41 0-18.957 5.66-22.64 16.98-3.684 11.32-5.526 28.75-5.526 52.29zM222.759.242c24.887 0 42.339 8.76 52.356 26.28 10.018 17.52 15.027 42.406 15.027 74.66s-5.01 57.095-15.027 74.525c-10.017 17.43-27.47 26.145-52.356 26.145-24.887 0-42.339-8.715-52.357-26.145-10.017-17.43-15.026-42.271-15.026-74.525 0-32.254 5.009-57.14 15.026-74.66C180.42 9.001 197.872.241 222.76.241zm221.824 154.711h-22.102V197h-37.6v-42.047h-77.355v-33.557l71.83-118.593h43.125V124.9h22.102v30.053zM384.882 124.9V40.537l-48.92 84.363h48.92z"
            fillRule="nonzero"
          />
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div className="h-full w-full flex justify-center items-center relative z-10">
        <div className="p-6 text-center">
          <h2 className="uppercase text-xl lg:text-5xl font-black">
            We are sorry, Page not found!
          </h2>
          <p className="mt-3 uppercase text-sm lg:text-base font-semibold text-gray-900">
            The page you are looking for might have been removed had its name
            changed or is temporarily unavailable.
          </p>
          <div className="text-center">
            <Link href="/">
              <a
                className="mt-6 m-auto bg-primary text-white py-4 px-6 w-1/3 block rounded-full tracking-wide
                font-semibold font-display focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline hover:bg-primaryAccent
                shadow-lg transition-css"
              >
                Back To Homepage
              </a>
            </Link>

            <button
              onClick={() => router.back()}
              className="mt-6 m-auto bg-primary text-white py-4 px-6 w-1/4 block rounded-full tracking-wide
                  font-semibold font-display focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline hover:bg-primaryAccent
                  shadow-lg transition-css"
            >
              Go Back
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default ErrorPage;
```

### In the case of TailwindCSS, you should use `h-full and w-full` instead of `h-screen and w-screen`.

Also, in your specific case it's this line that was breaking everything, most likely:

```
<div className="h-screen w-screen flex justify-center items-center relative z-10">
```

As you already have this applied to the parent element:

```
<div className="bg-gray-900 h-screen w-screen flex justify-center items-center absolute z-0">
```

It's all wrong semantically in your code. This is ugly work-arounding.

You haven't provided the tailwind.config.js, so some of the colors in the demo are missing due to missing custom TailwidnCSS class names values.

But this is basically the same code with an exception of eplacing all -screen properties with -full and also removing the bottom padding of the svg, as on most of the screens, the svg has too much spacing and then consumes >100vh space of the screen and is not positioned at the center vertically, but rather has starneg white space at the bottom of the page.

https://dpd0jl.sse.codesandbox.io/

Comment: `h-full` and `w-full` instead of `*-screen` solve the issue for me (with TailwindCSS).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to have a `parent relative` div

```
<div class="h-screen w-screen relative">

    <!-- 404 -->
    <div class="bg-gray-900 flex justify-center items-center absolute inset-0 z-0"> // inset-0 is important
        <svg></svg>
    </div>
    
    <!-- content -->
    <div class="flex justify-center items-center absolute inset-0 z-10">
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your design.

I would recommend changing h-screen to min-h-screen.

You can check out an example using your code in the following link.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/eD7VEDN5AR

Comment: It's working for medium and small screens, But it still breaks the responsiveness in large and extra-large screens

Comment: Add `min-h-screen` to your `body` tag; that might be the problem.

Comment: Sorry, it's still the same. https://play.tailwindcss.com/l1uGRlqvGO